# Eclipse doesn't correctly export resources

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, export

When I run my program from Java, everything is fine. If I export my program to a runable .jar, the program doesn't start. 
It does start thou, when I copy the resource folder with my pics NEXT TO the runable .jar. The resource folder is usually in my src folder.
The runnable jar does include a resource folder with the pics.
Its next to the folder with the package name.

I used

```
Icon cancelIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/cancelIcon.png"));
```

and

```
Icon cancelIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/cancelIcon.png"));
```

Why doesn't my program work after export?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was, that eclipse doesn't care about case sensitivity in paths, but the exported jar does. 
I had a file "animation.GIF" and in the sourcecode stood "animation.gif". Eclipse didn't care, the jar did.

Answer (score 0):

> *It does start thou, when I copy the resource folder with my pics NEXT TO the runable .jar.*

This is because when you export runnable .jar it gives you three option under **Library handling**

- Extract required libraries into generated JAR
- Package required libraries into generated JAR
- Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR

you might have selected 3rd one i.e why when you copy sub-folder next to .jar it run properly....

I would suggest to select 1st *(Extract ...)* while exporting and try again to run your .jar....

Your `resources` folder *(containing image)* should be inside your `src` folder...and to set `imageIcon` in java you can use `Toolkit` like this..

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
  private JPanel MainPanel;

  public static void main (String[] args){      //--main method --//
      Main window = new Main();
      window.setVisible(true);
  }

  private Main(){                               //--constructor --//

      MainPanel = new JPanel(null);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/cancelIcon.png")));

      this.add(MainPanel);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps..